# Post-apocalyptic future in which almost no one can read

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic

In the 90s (or early 2000s) I read a post-apocalyptic story in *Asimovs* about a man and a younger person entering an abandoned military facility to get supplies or information.  The man is very old (but not looking that way) - he's from the pre-apocalyptic era before an engineered disease made it impossible for people to read.  The older man has been testing younger folks in his tribe to see if the disease has abated (there is some sign that it has).  This is not Butler's "Speech Sounds" - everyone can still speak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is "[This Old Man](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?102286)" (2004) by Steven Popkes.  As you guessed, it was published in *Asimov's*, January 2004.  You can [read it](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v28n01_2004-01/page/n101/mode/2up) at the Internet Archive.

The titular man, Old Man Hibbert, is indeed *very* old; he's been around since ancient Sumeria:

> He stood up. "2100 BC. 'BC' means 'before Christ.' Remember the date? April 5, 2260. And 2260 is 2260 AD, which means after Christ but only looks absurd to me since I'm the only one anymore that can read the letters. The sum of 2100 and 2260 is 4360, so I'm four thousand, three hundred and sixty years old." He stretched his back. "Of course, the dates are approximate; when I finally got around to going out on the digs myself, even I couldn't tell exactly what period of Sumerian culture I was born in. I remember forests and farms and cool, wet springs. The digs were in the middle of the desert."

He keeps trying to teach kids to read:

> Maybe it was because I didn't see him teaching very often, but it struck me how gentle he was with these kids. He'd read to them and try to get them to say the letters. They'd repeat after him but when he held one up and asked them what it was, they'd fidget and laugh. He laughed, too, and tried something else, a different book, a drawing, having Bruno do a trick. Heck, I tried to read with them. I'd like to be able to tell the old man I could read. It wasn't any use. I couldn't tell the letters apart. And I *knew* they were letters; the old man had told me often enough. I could see the numbers without much trouble.

Old Man Hibbert calls it the "reading plague," and things have been getting better:

> He rubbed his eyes and looked tired. "It's better than it used to be."
>
> "It is?"
>
> He smiled. "Oh, yes. The generation after the plague couldn't read numbers. They had trouble counting. Some of them couldn't see a drawing on paper. Others were actually retarded. Whatever this plague is, it hits a very precise area of the brain. But, as precise as it is, there are still side effects and collateral damage. Now, we have numbers—and money—again."
>
> I didn't like the sound of it. "'Are,' sir? Isn't the plague gone?"
>
> "I don't know." He stepped down and stretched in the afternoon sun. "It could have been a plague that did specific damage to the human genome, and we're seeing the effects. Or, it could still be lingering around here in some reservoir and reinfecting each generation. I can't tell if we're adapting to the damage or generating resistance."

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: AD is Anno Domini, 'in the year of the Lord'.